# Quotient of Lie rings and quotient of Lie groups!

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there any correspondence between Lie rings and Lie groups such that if one proves for a Lie algebra $g$ with ideal $I$ that $g/I$ is a Lie algebra, then the same result holds automatically for the quotient ring?

Thanks in advance AB

Comment: You need not prove that the quotient of a Lie algebra by an ideal is a Lie algebra, that's done in books. BTW, what do you mean by 'quotient ring'?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What quotient ring do you mean?  What does a Lie group have to do with anything?

Comment: Take a Lie ring and build a quotient out of it! Here I mean if $g$ is  a Lie algebra and $L$ its Lie ring (an associative ring equipped with a bracket operator $[,]$ can be made into a Lie ring), then $L/I$ defines a quotient ring where I is a two-sided ideal in $L$.

Comment: Lie ring = universal enveloping algebra? 

Comment: @Sam Gunningham: Exactly!

Comment: I think this still needs to be clarified.  Take $g$ to be a Lie algebra, $I \subseteq g$ an ideal.  Are you asking whether $U(I)$ (the universal enveloping algebra of $I$) is an ideal in the universal enveloping algebra $U(g)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not posed in a clear way but, if I am interpreting correctly, it is enough to recall  that the universal enveloping algebra $U(g/I)$ of the Lie algebra quotient $g/I$ is isomorphic to $U(g)/B$, where $B$ is the two-sided ideal of $U(g)$ generated by $I$. (Of course, here $g$ is identified with its isomorphic image in $U(g)$.) This is a rather elementary fact: see e.g. Theorem 1 in Chapter 5 of the book "N. Jacobson: Lie algebras".